# Slowly updating side input using windowing does not work

Tags: python, apache-beam

I followed the code snippet of [Slowly updating side input using windowing example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-side-input-using-windowing) but it printed nothing.
It only runs **side_input** instead of the whole.
I use DirectRunner for this.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.periodicsequence import PeriodicImpulse
from apache_beam.transforms.window import TimestampedValue
from apache_beam.transforms import window

def cross_join(left, rights):
    for x in rights:
        yield left, x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = list(range(1, 100))
    pattern = 'pat'
    main_interval = 10
    side_interval = 5
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
    side_input = (
            pipeline
            | 'PeriodicImpulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=side_interval, apply_windowing=True)
            | 'MapToFileName' >> beam.Map(lambda x: pattern + str(x)))
    main_input = (
            pipeline
            | 'MpImpulse' >> beam.Create(data)
            | 'MapMpToTimestamped' >> beam.Map(lambda src: TimestampedValue(src, src))
            | 'WindowMpInto' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(main_interval)))
    result = (
            main_input
            | 'ApplyCrossJoin' >> beam.FlatMap(cross_join, rights=beam.pvalue.AsIter(side_input))
            | 'log' >> beam.Map(print))
    res = pipeline.run()
    res.wait_until_finish()
```

thanks and regards.

Comment: Where are you running this code? You are not getting any error, just nothing is printed? Aren't you missing `()` in `yield`?

Comment: @PjoterS, I use DirectRunner,  no difference for the `()`, I also put a print() inside cross_join() but nothing prints out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Python FnApiRunner does not yet support streaming mode. It is trying to run `PeriodicImpulse` to completion before executing the next stage of the pipeline. This is curently being worked on at [BEAM-7514](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7514).

Unfortunately, it looks like the `BundleBasedDirectRunner` which can do streaming in Python has issues with `PeriodicImpulse` as well.

You could try using a "real" runner, e.g. Flink in local mode, by passing `runner='Flink'` to your pipeline creation.

Note also that your side input needs to be windowed as well, and the side and main inputs will be lined up by window.